# Command execution on closing "X" Tkinter MessageBox

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, messagebox, tkmessagebox

I am trying to restart my main GUI/Halt the program flow when I Click on the "X" button in my tkinter messagebox . Any idea how can I do this ?

PS: I have read the many threads about closing the main GUI itself but nothing specific to messagebox

By default , my code proceeds to ask me for an output path using the filedailog.askdirectory() method when clicking "ok", or  on closing the messagebox

[My message box and the main GUI in the background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8Omb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no simple way to add a custom handler to the "X" button. I think it's better to use [`messagebox.askokcancel()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.messagebox.html#tkinter.messagebox.askokcancel) variation of messageboxes instead of `showinfo`, and halt the program if the returned result is False:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox, filedialog

root = tk.Tk()


def show_messagebox():
    result = messagebox.askokcancel("Output path", "Please select an output file path")
    if result:
        filedialog.askdirectory()
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Program is halted")


tk.Button(root, text="Show messagebox", command=show_messagebox).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Or, even simpler, you can just show `filedialog.askdirectory()` directly. If the user doesn't want to choose directory, they can click on the "Cancel" button, and then the program checks if there was empty value returned, and halts if so:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox, filedialog

root = tk.Tk()


def show_askdirectory():
    directory = filedialog.askdirectory(title="Please select an output file path")
    if not directory:
        messagebox.showinfo(message="The program is halted")
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo(message="Chosen directory: " + directory)


tk.Button(root, text="Choose directory", command=show_askdirectory).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That second option is actually a pretty smart solution. Thanks !